# Artifactory, poor download speed for files

Tags: performance, artifactory

In our company we work with Artifactory Commercial license and currently 7.55.8 as repository for Maven.
We currently have 779,734 artifacts stored in the repository.
Besides the small artifacts we have some in the size of 1 GB and had to notice that the download speed of these artifacts is very poor. A request of a larger file makes an average of only 20Mb/s on the LAN. Protocol is HTTP, OS is Linux

Same Problem on a fresh installed Artifactory on Linux with large files

Does anyone know this problem or have an idea how to change it or investigate it further?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the number of artifacts and the environment type you have described, we need to look at it from the network bandwidth's aspect. In this particular scenario, network latency seems to be the main issue.

Also, if the number of active clients are more and you could see slow transactions from the database end, you may consider tuning the instance resources as well. ([Guide to tune the resources](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-tune-artifactory-for-heavy-loads/))